# vim NERDTree disable caching

Tags: caching, vim, nerdtree

How to disable directory caching. I need sometimes to edit files through sshfs and while going through directories I see:

```
NERDTree: Please wait, caching a large dir ...
```

Comment: If you didn't find a suitable option in `:h nerdtree` then you can't.

Comment: I use sshfs too. I'm always disappointed when NERDTree takes ~5-6 seconds to read a directory with 400 files while ls takes ~500 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

*Caching* in the context of NERD_Tree means reading in the directory contents and storing it in a Vim variable, so that when you close and open the same directory again later, it happens instantly instead of taking noticeable time.

I'm afraid the only options you have is either

1. do not open directories that have many files or are on a slow file system
2. recursively open all directories in NERD_Tree once when you start Vim; this will take a very long time, but any navigation after that will be quick (until you restart Vim).